# Получить ввод с клавиатуры на самописной OS

Tags: c, ассемблер, клавиатура, ос, osdev

Как с помощью Assembler'a и C получить ввод с клавиатуры? В OS есть функции типа `printf` и консоль (для нее ввод как раз и нужен).

**P.S.** [Этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263514/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-an-homemade-os) видел, но он не помог.

Comment: А какой API предоставляет OS?

Comment: Assembler и C :) Я прикрутил `stdlib.h`, `stdio.h`, `string.h`, `ctype.h`, `stdint.h` и несколько своих библиотек.

Comment: То есть вы имеете в виду, что _вся_ рантайм-библиотека C реализована? Тогда всё просто, используйте `scanf`.

Comment: Нет. Я имел в виду, что есть наброски библиотек. `scanf` пока нету.

Comment: Окей, тогда _какие_ функции есть? // И да, в принципе функции ввода-вывода должна предоставлять консольная подсистема. Как она это делает — её внутренние подробности, зависящие от того, как конкретно устроена консоль в вашей ОС.

Comment: printf, puts, putchar, функции для вывода в термина (terminal_write и т.п), memcmp, memcpy, memmove, memset, strlen, va_start, va_end, va_arg, функции ядра (kernel_main и т.п).

Comment: Мне нужно, чтоб просто считать. Чтоб клавиатура слала какой-то сигнал или еще что-то. Что бы обработать что было :)

Comment: (1) А куда выводит `printf`? на терминал через `terminal_write`? (2) а есть ли `terminal_read`?

Comment: Выводит на `terminal_write`. Функция пихает в видео память полученные символы. `terminal_read` нет. Я не знаю, как ее реализовать.

Comment: Смотрите. Консоль запрашивает чтение клавиатуры у соответствующей подсистемы. Например, если консоль на терминале, то у оконной. Консоль сама по себе не должна лезть на уровень сигналов от клавиатуры: представьте себе случай, когда у вас на экране две консоли, что ж они обе будут получать ввод одновременно? Наоборот, консоль должна _получать_ посылаемые ей нажатия клавиш (возможно, после трансляции на нужный язык) от своего контейнера. А уж контейнер получает их либо от оконной, либо от консольной подсистемы. Как-то так.

Comment: Э... Я так понял, речь идёт об аналогах ah=01h,06h,07h,08h,0Ah для int21h, или eax=3 для int80h, так, что ли?

Comment: Отлично. Но как этот поток получить? Вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: @reload: Какой поток?

Comment: Ну, не поток, а нажатые клавиши или что она посылает?

Comment: Ммм... "Функция пихает в видео память полученные символы" — это уже неправильно. Не дело консоли знать, где она бежит: в полном экране, в окне, или вообще через ssh.

Comment: @reload, получить - см. порт 60h. Если это PC, конечно :)

Comment: Она и не знает. Откуда ей знать? Просто есть указатель на видео память монитора. Туда после обработки помещаются нужные символы.

Comment: Нет никакого монитора, и видеопамяти нет. Ваще нет, как явления.

Comment: Должна быть примерно такая цепочка: (1) ОС обрабатывает аппаратное прерывание и возможно перекодирует физическую клавишу в виртуальную (поддержка языков). (2) У ОС есть клиенты клавиатуры — консольная и оконная подсистемы. Та из них, которая активна, получает от ОС нажатую клавишу. (3) Консольная подсистема посылает пришедший символ активной консоли в её stdin. Оконная подсистема посылает оконное сообщение окну, держащему фокус. (4) Приложение в консоли читает символ из stdin. Оконное приложение обрабатывает оконные сообщения.

Comment: Превратил в ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должна быть примерно такая цепочка:

1. ОС обрабатывает аппаратное прерывание и определят скан-код клавиши. Возможно перекодирует физическую клавишу в виртуальную (поддержка языков).
2. У ОС есть клиенты клавиатуры — консольная и оконная подсистемы. Та из них, которая активна, получает от ОС нажатую клавишу. Если перекодировка в виртуальные клавиши не происходит на уровне ОС, она происходит здесь.
3. Консольная подсистема посылает пришедший символ активной консоли в её `stdin`. Оконная подсистема посылает оконное сообщение окну, держащему фокус.
4. Приложение в консоли читает символ из `stdin`. Оконное приложение обрабатывает оконные сообщения.
5. Если в консоли режим ввода с echo, консоль выводит этот символ на себя. Это делается путём добавления в консольный буфер. Оконный контрол, занимающийся вводом, обычно находится в режиме отображения поступивших символов. Он модифицирует строку, содержащую свой текст, и отсылает оконной подсистеме запрос не перерисовку.
6. При изменении консольного буфера консольная подсистема перерисовывает содержимое консоли. При этом, возможно, нужно будет сдвинуть другие строки. Перерисовка может происходить прямо в текстовом участке видеопамяти. При приходе запроса на перерисовку оконная подсистема ждёт некоторое время накопления таких запросов, и затем посылает запрос на перерисовку видимым окнам, находящимся в «грязном» участке экрана. Окна для отрисовки текста в свою очередь вызывают функции типа `DrawText` оконной подсистемы. Эта функция модифицирует содержимое текущего собираемого фрейма либо прямо в видеопамяти, либо в промежуточном буфере. (В случае с X Window system есть ещё промежуточные уровни логики.)